# Generate hierarchical entitiy objects using Entity framework database first and from a SQL VIEW

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I know how to generate  entity objects using database first approch  using SQL TABLES. However I am struggling to create a hierarchical entites from a SQL VIEW. This is because I am unable to assign a primary key and foreign key to the  id and parent fields ( see below)

An example SQL VIEW is as follows:

```
id, name,  parent
1, John, null
2, Bill, 1
3, Jane, 2
4, Bob, 2
```

The underlying view is made of  joins and unions hence I cannot use a SQL TABLE

There appears to be other examples of code first approaches but I'm looking for a solution that can use my existing view.

Comment: what if you try somethign like :var test =  dbcontext.Sql<YOURPOCO>("Select id, name,  parent FROM yourview")

Comment: You can certainly use views with Entity Framework.... or are you asking how to INSERT into the view?

Comment: hi,   I'm esentially trying to get a json output (read only) with nested child objects based on the view. I'm getting stuck in how to let the ef designer know  the relationship between parent and child ( id and parent key in above sample)